# Как передать значение в input?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, create-react-app

Подскажите, как сделать проверку input. Если есть параметр у ссылки searchParams.get("q"), то он передается в input, а если его нет, то input пустой? И если параметр searchParams.get("q") есть, то в input он передается 1 раз т.к. input потом можно было бы очистить

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(
  (e) => {
    if (searchParams.get("q") !== null) {
    setSearchValue(searchParams.get("q"));
    } else {
      setSearchValue(e.target.value);
    }
  },
  [searchParams]
);
```

Нужно сделать useEffect, который будет следить за state и передавать значение. Спасибо всем кто мне помог т.е. мне. Надеюсь мой ответ поможет кому-то и он сэкономит свое время =)